# Cannot Click Custom UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview, firebaseui

I have a custom UICollectionView cell with an imageView and a label, as listed below:

```
import UIKit

class PollCell: UICollectionViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var pollQuestion: UILabel!

}
```

I want to make each populated cell clickable and then pass information from that clicked cell into a new ViewController. Below is the ViewController that populates the custom cell.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseDatabaseUI
import FirebaseStorageUI


private let reuseIdentifier = "PollCell"

class TrendingViewController: UICollectionViewController {

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
var dataSource: FUICollectionViewDataSource!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Register cell classes

    self.dataSource = self.collectionView?.bind(to: self.ref.child("Polls")) { collectionView, indexPath, snap in
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PollCell
        /* populate cell */
        cell.pollQuestion.text = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "question").value as! String?
        let urlPollImage = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "image_URL").value as! String?
        cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: urlPollImage!), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "Fan_Polls_Logo.png"))
        //Comment
        return cell
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

 public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,   didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
print(indexPath)
 }


 }
```

I also have some code to "invert" the cells that populate in my inverted ViewController:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class InvertedStackLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
  let cellHeight: CGFloat = 100.00 // Your cell height here...

override func prepare() {
    super.prepare()
}

override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    var layoutAttrs = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    if let collectionView = self.collectionView {
        for section in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfSections {
            if let numberOfSectionItems = numberOfItemsInSection(section) {
                for item in 0 ..< numberOfSectionItems {
                    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
                    let layoutAttr = layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)

                    if let layoutAttr = layoutAttr, layoutAttr.frame.intersects(rect) {
                        layoutAttrs.append(layoutAttr)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return layoutAttrs
}

override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    let layoutAttr = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
    let contentSize = self.collectionViewContentSize

    layoutAttr.frame = CGRect(
        x: 0, y: contentSize.height - CGFloat(indexPath.item + 1) * cellHeight,
        width: contentSize.width, height: cellHeight)

    return layoutAttr
}

func numberOfItemsInSection(_ section: Int) -> Int? {
    if let collectionView = self.collectionView,
        let numSectionItems = collectionView.dataSource?.collectionView(collectionView, numberOfItemsInSection: section)
    {
        return numSectionItems
    }

    return 0
}

override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
    get {
        var height: CGFloat = 0.0
        var bounds = CGRect.zero

        if let collectionView = self.collectionView {
            for section in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfSections {
                if let numItems = numberOfItemsInSection(section) {
                    height += CGFloat(numItems) * cellHeight
                }
            }

            bounds = collectionView.bounds
        }

        return CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: max(height, bounds.height))
    }
}

override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    if let oldBounds = self.collectionView?.bounds,
        oldBounds.width != newBounds.width || oldBounds.height != newBounds.height
    {
        return true
    }

    return false
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your issue? what you need to achieve?

Comment: I have a UICollectionView with custom cells. New to Swift. Right now, the cells are not clickable. I want the cell to be clickable and to navigate to a new ViewController, passing data from the clicked cell. Right now, I cannot even get the cell to be clickable.

Comment: @tccpg288 based on your comment above, using the `collection​View(_:​did​Select​Item​At:​)` method might not be what you want to do. I provided an answer that may fit your needs.

Comment: much appreciated, I essentially want to make sure I have the clicks activated before I start playing around with segue

Answer (score 2):

You must to implement this method of `UICollectionViewDelegate`

```
   public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

     debugPrint("this works")
    }
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: I added code to test and see if my clicks are being recognized with no result. New to this and really appreciate your help.

Comment: @tccpg288 In the implementation of this method, you provide the logic to accomplish your needs. Add the code you want executed when a cell is tapped between the `{ }`.

Comment: So my code looks correct? Keep in mind I am using Firebase data soure and it may be different. I simply want to print to the log on click to test if it is working, and it is not printing to the log. I did hear that the iOS emulators have issues printing to the logs.

Comment: @tccpg288 check if `self.collectionView.delegate` is not null and is equal to your `viewController`, if not you must add in your `viewDidLoad` this `self.collectionView.delegate = self`

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: @tccpg288 check `if(self.collectionView.delegate != nil){debugPrint("is not nil")}else{debugPrint("is nil")}` its weird because the `UICollectionViewController` must have defined delegate as self

Answer (score 1):

This Function used to select the row of your collection view

```
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

 }
```

Then you use function call. Whatever you need, just Defined the inside function. And easily called the function during the selected the row (inside the didSelectItemAt indexPath)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have enabled UserIntraction for both UILabel and UIImageView, because both have default value as false.

```
  self.dataSource = self.collectionView?.bind(to: self.ref.child("Polls")) { collectionView, indexPath, snap in
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PollCell
    /* populate cell */
    cell.pollQuestion.userInteractionEnabled = true;
     cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true;
    cell.pollQuestion.text = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "question").value as! String?
    let urlPollImage = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "image_URL").value as! String?
    cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: urlPollImage!), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "Fan_Polls_Logo.png"))
    //Comment
    return cell
}
```

Then you need to use of UICollectionViewDelegate method:

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
  }
```

Comment: Do these go in the viewDidLoad() method?

Comment: Yes this you need to add in the viewDidLoad() method.

Answer (score 1):

Add a segue in your storyboard from the cell to the view controller you want to transition to. You can use the prepare for segue method, [`prepare(for:sender:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare), to pass your data. Using the `segue` ([`UIStoryboarySegue` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistoryboardsegue)) parameter, you can access the 'destinationViewController`.

Check out the [View Controller for iOS Programming Guide: Using Segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html) for more information about using segues.